# SQL - How to extract the rows that meet certain conditions

Tags: sql

I will describe my problem and also show you what I tried to do in order to solve it.

so first I have 3 tables like that:
[image]

I want to get the status and the orderNumber from the orders table for all the orders that the productLine include these 3 categories ( Vintage Cars, Classic Cars, Motorcycles)

```
SELECT o.status, o.orderNumber
FROM orders o
WHERE EXISTS(
         SELECT p.productLine 
         FROM products p 
         WHERE p.productLine  IN ('Vintage Cars', 'Classic Cars', 'Motorcycles'))
```

the query above is what I tried to do, but it returns me every row.

I think I don't understand how it possible to check if the productLine includes Vintage Cars and Classic Cars and Motorcycles.
thanks!

Comment: The subquery needs an orders condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select o.status, o.orderNumber
from orders o join
     orderdetails od
     on o.ordernumber = od.ordernumber join
     products p
     on od.productcode = p.productcode
where p.productLine in ('Vintage Cars', 'Classic Cars', 'Motorcycles')
group by o.status, o.orderNumber
having count(distinct p.productLine) = 3;
```

The `having` clause is checking that all three product lines are present in an `order`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the different variables you are querying by, otherwise your orders table won't know which products or orders you want to select.

I would suggest you do a JOIN on the 3 tables, or alternatively you can nest 3 different subqueries like I did here:

```
SELECT o.status, o.orderNumber
FROM orders o
WHERE o.orderNumber in 
    (SELECT d.orderNumber
    FROM orderdetails d
    WHERE d.productCode in
           (
            SELECT p.productCode 
            FROM products p 
            WHERE p.productLine  IN ('Vintage Cars', 'Classic Cars', 'Motorcycles'))
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This . Join orderdetails with products and order table based on code and number repectively and check for productline .

```
SELECT d.status, o.orderNumber
FROM orderdetails d,orders o,products p
where d.productcode=p.productcode
and d.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
and p.productLine  IN ('Vintage Cars', 'Classic Cars', 'Motorcycles') ;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: It might also increase the likelihood that your answer will get upvotes.  I certainly do not upvote -- nor condone upvoting -- answers that use archaic syntax.